# SWIG C++ interface of template classes

Tags: python, c++, swig

I would like to create a python interface for my C++ class. 
This class relies on some template arguments, which have been declared partly by the keyword "using", which is only partially supported by SWIG.
This is why I would like to declare them more direct in the SWIG interface file. Unfortunately only the non-commented section compiles e.g. functor_gaussianF as argument it complains that it is not declared.

This is how I defined the functors in the C++ header:

```
template<class T> using functor_gaussian = DistFunction<T, som_learn<T>, fcn_gaussian_nhood<T>, fcn_rad_decay<T>, fcn_lrate_decay<T> >;
template<class T> using functor_bubble = DistFunction<T, som_learn<T>, fcn_bubble_nhood<T>, fcn_rad_decay<T>, fcn_lrate_decay<T> >;
template<class T> using functor_cutgaussian = DistFunction<T, som_learn<T>, fcn_cutgaussian_nhood<T>, fcn_rad_decay<T>, fcn_lrate_decay<T> >;
template<class T> using functor_epanechicov = DistFunction<T, som_learn<T>, fcn_epanechicov_nhood<T>, fcn_rad_decay<T>, fcn_lrate_decay<T> >;
template<class T> using functor_mexican = DistFunction<T, som_learn<T>, fcn_mexican_nhood<T>, fcn_rad_decay<T>, fcn_lrate_decay<T> >;
```

Here, in the interface file I cannot use them, but need to define them somehow again:

```
%{
#include "SOMNet.h"
%}

%include "SOMNet.h" 

namespace ANN {
  %template(functor_gaussianF) DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_gaussian_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >;
  %template(functor_bubbleF) DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_bubble_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >;
  %template(functor_cutgaussianF) DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_cutgaussian_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >;
  %template(functor_epanechicovF) DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_epanechicov_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >;
  %template(functor_mexicanF) DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_mexican_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >;

  %template(SOMNetGaussF) SOMNet<float, DistFunction<float, som_learn<float>, fcn_gaussian_nhood<float>, fcn_rad_decay<float>, fcn_lrate_decay<float> >>;
  /*
  %template(SOMNetBubbleF) SOMNet<float, functor_bubble>;
  %template(SOMNetCGaussF) SOMNet<float, functor_cutgaussian>;
  %template(SOMNetEpanF) SOMNet<float, functor_epanechicov>;
  %template(SOMNetMexicanF) SOMNet<float, functor_mexican>;
  */
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. You could consider instantiating all your templates and write non-templated versions of the functions that you need to wrap. In this way, you can make a proper ABI for your language and let your SWIG wrapper link to a shared object.

Comment: Now I understand, why instantiation is used in libraries :)

Comment: It can get complicated with shared libraries (.so or .dll) using templates. You need to explicitly instantiate everything and if you have non-POD types on your interface, you easily run into trouble with heap allocations.